# Daisy chain of two monitors through DisplayPort does not work on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, displayport

I have just installed Ubuntu in an attempt to migrate to Linux, but I can't get it to handle two monitor setup.

One monitor connected to DP works alright (Dell U2715H).

When I connect the second monitor (Dell U2414H) to the first one through DisplayPort (daisy chain), the second monitor just mirrors the content of the first one.

The second monitor not shown in Settings->Displays.

Is there an option to run two daisy chained monitors in Ubuntu?

**System config:**

```
~$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao PRO [Radeon R7 370 / R9 270/370 OEM] [1002:6811]

~$ xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 597mm x 336mm
   2560x1440     59.95 +
   2048x1152     60.00  
   1920x1200     59.88  
   1920x1080     60.00*   50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98  
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1200x960      59.99  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       75.00    60.00    59.94  
   720x400       70.08  
HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: What version and kernel are you using?

Comment: Apparently you are not the only one: `https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2301503`.  Notice the post in there: `Prior to enabling DisplayPort 1.2 on the U2715H, both monitors came up fine in mirrored mode, though neither NVIDIA X Server Settings nor Displays detected the VG248. After enabling DisplayPort 1.2 features on the U2715H, The VG248 was detected, but blank. Now everything is OK (until the system sleeps or reboots, presumably). ` My feeling... I would connect the 2nd monitor to HDMI. Saves a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: @Robby1212, 16.04 LTS `~$ uname -r` --> `4.8.0-52-generic`